# Ruby only checks for first element of a boolean expression?

Tags: ruby, boolean-expression

Here's my code:

```
array = ["b", "c", "a", "e", "d", "g", "i", "f"]
array.each_index do |letter| 
  if array[letter] == ("a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u")
    puts "found #{array[letter]}"
  end
end
```

I'd expect it to return this:

```
found a
found e
found i
```

but instead I only get

```
found a
```

What's more, if I change the order of the elements within () on line 3, e.g. like this

```
if array[letter] == ("e" || "a" || "i" || "o" || "u")
```

the code returns `found e` instead of `found a`.

I think I understand the problem—Ruby is only checking `array` for the first element within (). But can anyone explain why this is? I'd expect it to check for all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x || y` is `x` if `x` is truthy, `y` otherwise. `"a"` is truthy (everything except `nil` and `false` is truthy, those two and *only* those two are falsey), therefore `"a" || whatever_it_doesnt_matter` is *always* `"a"`.

So,

```
if array[letter] == ("a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u")
```

is equivalent to

```
if array[letter] == ("a" || ("e" || ("i" || ("o" || "u"))))
```

which evaluates to

```
if array[letter] == ("a" || ("i" || ("o" || "u")))
```

which evaluates to

```
if array[letter] == ("a" || ("o" || "u"))
```

which evaluates to

```
if array[letter] == ("a" || "u")
```

which evaluates to

```
if array[letter] == "a"
```

Comment: Plus `||` short circuits, so you don't need to go beyond `("a" || (...))`.

Comment: I expect @pjs's comment is directed to your choice of the word "evaluates".

Answer (score 3):

The boolean statement is logically wrong.
It should be

```
array[letter] == "e" || array[letter] == "a" || array[letter] == "i" || array[letter] == "o" || array[letter] == "u"
```

Or more idiomatic

```
["a" , "e" , "i" , "o" ,"u"].include?(array[letter])
```

Answer (score 1):

See the explanation from @JörgWMittag why your code doesn't work.

You could write :

```
array = %w(b c a e d g i f)

vowels = %w(a e i o u)
array.each do |letter|
  puts "found #{letter}" if vowels.include? letter
end
```

or just :

```
array.grep(/[aeiou]/).each do |vowel|
  puts "found #{vowel}"
end
```

Note that since Ruby is dynamic, variable names are really important.

This is syntactically correct :

```
array.each_index do |letter|
```

but it gives the wrong impression that `letter` is a string with a letter inside.